# Drawing by pixel without smearing or blurring

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I am going crazy trying to figure out this very simple thing.

I want a drawing tool (like pen or pencil or paintbrush) that can just paint pixels directly as pixels. Thus if the size of the tip is 1px, and I click once, I get a 1px square. If I click and drag 5px, I get a 1px x 5px line. No smearing, no vectors, no curve fitting or stylizing or texturizing or anything like that. How do I do it?

Comment: erm.. the pencil tool in Photoshop.

Comment: ok, I'll bite. Where is the pencil tool?

Comment: Click and hold on the paintbrush tool. The flyout menu will display a pencil as one of its options.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pencil tool in Photoshop;

[image: pencil]